# Printing out the wrong value in array

Tags: php, arrays, html, key

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$highNum = null;
$longest = null;

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    $num = strlen($value);
    $arr = nl2br("$key: $num\n");
    echo $arr;
    if ($num > $highNum) {
        $highNum = $num;
        $longest = $key;
    }
}
?>

<p>The longest entry is: <?= htmlentities($_SERVER[$longest]); ?></p>
<p>And its value is: <?= print(strval($highNum)); ?></p>
```

When I run the code it prints out the longest entry but when I print out the value, say for example that the value is 746, I get 7461. I've been stuck at this one for quite a while now and I can't seem to get rid of the one at the end. If I remove 1 from the value I get 7451 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this:

```
<p>And its value is: <?= strval($highNum); ?></p>
```

Since you're doing `echo` already, you don't need to use `print` again.

Note: `print` also return `1` upon successful printing.

Comment: Oh ok, still fairly new to this. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Makaronen That's totally fine. No problem. I'm glad I could help!